# How to install Firebird SQL version 3 or 4 on modern Linux in 2023?

Tags: linux, firebird

I don't know if Firebird SQL community is sleeping or what but there is no manual how to install Firebird on nowadays Linux system (2023).

By modern Linux I mean Debian 12, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, Centos Stream 9, Fedora 36 or newer.

I found this article https://firebirdsql.org/en/news/how-to-install-firebird-3-0-and-4-0-on-linux/ but it is outdated and not working.
Firebird is using several third party libraries not available on these Linux versions.

Comment: Debian and Ubuntu provide the firebird3.0-server package. In any case, this question is not really suitable for Stack Overflow. I recommend you ask on [firebird-support](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-support).

Comment: Similarly, Fedora also provides a firebird package, https://packages.fedoraproject.org/pkgs/firebird/firebird/, and CentOS seems to provide it through EPEL.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am looking at Ubuntu 22 right now and I don't see that for specified version.

Comment: Oh, ok, I see that as packages... OK, I will try to explore how to install that. Thank you for direction.

Comment: It's listed on https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/database/firebird3.0-server

Comment: In 2023, installations and deployments usually took the form of Docker image distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I don't know why it did not work for me at the first time on new Linux installation but here is a simple way how to install Firebird 3.0 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS:

in terminal

```
sudo su

apt install firebird3.0-server
```

That's all.

If you want examples:

```
apt install firebird3.0-examples
```

If you want developer tools "isql-fb" console:

```
apt install firebird-dev
```

Tip: If you type "firebird" in terminal and firebird is not installed Linux will tell you what to do.

Also remember to execute "apt-get update" first.